# php: add array placement number to each array set e.g. 1 2 3

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a data set from mysql in a multidimensional array.

I am using a pagination script to show 10 per page of that array. I want to know how to append a number to each one like a scoring system. The array is sorted by the way that it will aways be so i want to to add a 1 to the first item, a 2 to the second item and so on.

I dont want to do this in the foreach that i output since this will not translate over to the second page where it would start back at 1.

Any ideas on how to attach a number in desc order to each item in the array so i can access it in the foreach and display it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not really sure what you want. Can you explain a bit better what you want to do and why? The index already provides a "natural" numbering of the elements.

Comment: How would i echo the index value?

Comment: can you post a sample of your array?

Comment: changed my answer a bit below

Comment: So the array i get from the db has a few items in each set, name, id, meta value. So i use a php script to paginate that array into sets of 10. Then i use a foreach to display each set of 10, I want to simply add a number (score) next to each item in the main array that i got from the db but have the pages keep the numbers going like the array groups do. So Page 1 will have 10 items show with number 1-10 next to each item, then page two will have 11-20 with 11-20 numbered next to each item and so on with all the pages there after until all items in array are numbered.

Comment: Each page only has 10 items from the full array in a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by doing some calculations based on which page i was on and the page count that was set and finding the size of the array from the db:

```
$all_members = get_users_ordered_by_meta('metavalue', 'desc'); 
$array_count = count($all_members);
$posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');

if ($page > 0) {
    $total_posts_avalible = ($posts_per_page * $page);
    $usernum = $total_posts_avalible - $posts_per_page;
}
```

Then i echo the $usernum in the foreach next to the name  of the user.

```
foreach() {
    $usernum++; 
    echo $usernum; echo $user_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fist you need to save the indexes in a $_SESSION variable:

```
$_SESSION['indexes'] = array();
```

and for multidimentional:

```
foreach( $array as $index=>$arrValue) {
            echo $index;
    foreach($arrValue as $index2=>$value){
            echo $index2;
            $_SESSION['indexes'][$index][$index2] = $value;
            echo $value;
     }
}
```

than you can go through all of the session indexes; where $index is the page or $index2 can be the row

Comment: if that is what type of array you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

Use the same math used to find the offset in your pagination query and start counting from there.

Comment: I guess that i dont know enough php to figure that out. I am using someone's script for pagination. Do you have any other insight that you can provide me with for this code?